# how to change url in browser with .htaccess after redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have this code in my htacccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domein\-een\.de$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domein\-een\.de$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.domein\.de\/een" [R=301,L]
```

The redirect works fine. But how can i change the url in the browser to : www.domein-een.de

Answer (score 1):

You can use these rules in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domein-een\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]

RewriteRule ^/?$ /een [L]
```